# Expression trees - different compiler behaviour for Action<T> in C# and VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, expression-trees

Given a simple piece of code which can return the name of a property in VB.NET:

```
Function NameForProperty(Of T)(ByVal field As Expression(Of Action(Of T))) As String

    Dim expression = DirectCast(field.Body, MemberExpression)

    Return expression.Member.Name

End Function
```

Which works like this:

```
NameForProperty(Of String)(Function (s) s.Length) ' ==> returns "Length"
```

And what I thought would have been the equivalent in C#:

```
string NameForProperty<T>(Expression<Action<T>> field)
{
    var expression = (MemberExpression)field.Body;

    return expression.Member.Name;
}
```

When I try to call the C# version:

```
NameForProperty<string>(s=>s.Length);
```

It returns a compiler error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object
>   expressions can be used as a statement

My question is: what is the difference between the two pieces of code?

**EDIT**

Ivan has provided an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811868/expression-trees-why-doesnt-the-c-equivalent-code-work/6811888#6811888) as to why the code does not work in C#. I am still curious as to why it does work in VB.NET.

**EDIT#2**

To be clear, I'm not looking for code which works -- simply why the code would work in VB.NET and not C#.

Comment: I *think* it might be due to the comment in the Remarks section of [the `Action<T>` MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx), more specifically "In Visual Basic, it must be defined by the Sub…End Sub construct. It can also be a method that returns a value that is ignored." It sounds like in Visual Basic the return value is just ignored, maybe due to the fact that you couldn't use `Sub` in your lambda expressions before? I haven't been working with .NET for a while though, so I might be off-base here.

Comment: This sounds to be the right clue. An Action in C# has no return value, its a void function which is not allowed to return. If lambdas are functions which can return in VB.NET its clear why it works in VB. Thats the reason I supposed using `Func` instead of `Action` in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class TypeMember<TClass>
{
    public static string PropertyName<TProp>(Expression<Func<TClass, TProp>> expression)
    {
        var body = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

        if (body == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("'expression' should be a property expression");

        return body.Member.Name;
    }
}

var propName = TypeMember<string>.PropertyName(s => s.Length);
```

The problem with your version lies in the fact that you're trying to use `Action<T>`. It returns nothing and thus lambda's body (`s.Length`) should be a statement. And it is not a statement actually. So compiler complains about it.

It would complain in the same way if you'd wrote

```
public void A()
{
    string s = "abc";
    s.Length;
}
```

It is the same thing.

I'm not an expert in VB.NET though, so I can't explain why it is working in VB, sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have seen the equivalent of this code -- i.e. I can get it to work. My main question is why does it have to be done this way in C#, when the other syntax is valid in VB.NET?

Comment: @user122211: It's not even an answer.

Comment: Seems reasonable. I will accept your answer if no one else can provide an explanation for why it works in VB.NET.

Comment: @user: the problem with C# version not in that it can't get the property name for you - it can really. The problem is that you're giving incorrect argument. Probably VB making some in-place corrections like 'casting'. It's not a real cast of course.

Comment: @user: could you take a look at compiled vb.net code? What IL vb produces actually? It would be interesting to compare it with C#-produced one.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the method to `Func` instead of `Action`.

Your statement is not valid as the error says. If you change the Action to Func it's ok, because `Length` is the return value.
Maybe the VB compiler has other checks / requirements.

Comment: Delegate System.Func<String> does not take 1 argumentss

Comment: Of course you'll have to use `Func<string,object>` or if you want to enforce a special type `Func<string,T>` to get it to work.